# Question about density of subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space,  $U$ an open subset and $A$ a dense subset in $X$.
How we prove that $\overline{U} = \overline{U \cap A}$?

I think that $\overline{U \cap A}\subset \overline{U}$, what's about the other inclusion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what definition(s) of closure do you have?

Comment: For the other inclusion, one way is to show that $U \subset \overline{U\cap A}$.

Comment: How to do this inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about the inclusion $\overline{U\cap A}\subseteq\overline U$ is right. So it remains to show $\overline{U}\subseteq\overline{U\cap A}$
**Hint:** Take an $x\in\overline U$. You have to show that for any open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ the set $V\cap(U\cap A)$ is non-empty (That is what it means for $x$ to be in the closure of $U\cap A$). What can you say about $U\cap V$? Is it empty/non-empty? Is it open?

Comment: I haven't understand how I prove that $V\cap(U\cap A)$ is non-empty.

Comment: @salma: $V\cap(U\cap A)=(V\cap U)\cap A$ the intersection of a non-empty open set $U\cap V$ with the dense set $A$.

Comment: and if $U$ is closed can we have $U = \overline{U \cap A}$?

Comment: @salma: If $U$ is also open, then yes.

Comment: but I suppose that $U$ is closed not open

Comment: Then $X=\Bbb R$, $A=\Bbb Q$, and $U=\{\pi\}$ is a counterexample.